# Find max values in a dict containing lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

The dict got the keys `years` and for each year it's a list of all the temperatures in all 12 months of that year. My goal is to print out a table starting with what year it is and then a new line for each month and the temp that month.

**The main thing is to mark the highest temp of all years with `(ATH)` and mark the highest temp in each year with `(YearHighest)`.**

```
My current code:
temp_dict= {
    "2010": [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 20, 29, 34, 2, 10, 1],
    "2011": [2, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 20, 9, 34, 2, 10, 10]
}

for key in temp_dict:
    print("Year",key,":")
    x=0
    for temps in temp_dict[key]:
        x=x+1
        print("Month "+str(x)+":%3d"%temps)
    print()
```

I'm not sure how to make the max function, I was thinking something like this but I can't get it to work:

```
for key in temp_dict:
    ATH = temp_dict[key]
    YearHigh = temp_dict[key][0]
        for temps in temp_dict[key]:
            if temps >= temp_dict[key][0]:
                 YearHigh = temps
    if YearHigh >= ATH:
         ATH = YearHigh
```

**How I want my output to look like:**

```
Year 2011 :
Month1:  2
Month2:  7
Month3:  4
Month4:  5
Month5:  9
Month6:  3
Month7: 20
Month8:  9
Month9: 34 (YearHighest)(ATH)
Month10:  2
Month11: 10
Month12: 10

Year 2010 :
Month1:  2
Month2:  3
Month3:  4
Month4:  5
Month5:  7
Month6:  3
Month7: 20
Month8: 29
Month9: 34 (YearHighest)(ATH)
Month10:  2
Month11: 10
Month12:  1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my code.

```
temp_dict= {
    "2010": [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 20, 29, 34, 2, 10, 1],
    "2011": [2, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 20, 9, 34, 2, 10, 10]
}

# Find the highest temp of all years
ath = max([ max(v) for v in temp_dict.values()])

for key in temp_dict:
    # Output Year
    print("Year{k}:".format(k=key))
    x=0
    # Find max
    max_value = max(temp_dict[key])
    for temps in temp_dict[key]:
        # Output Month 
        x=x+1
        s = "Month {x}:{v:3d}".format(x=str(x), v=temps)
        # Tag the max value
        if max_value == temps:
            s += "(YearHighest)" 
        if ath == temps:
            s += "(ATH)"
        print(s)
    print()
```

And this is my output.

```
Year2010:                                                                                                                                             
Month 1:  2                                                                                                                                           
Month 2:  3                                                                                                                                           
Month 3:  4                                                                                                                                           
Month 4:  5                                                                                                                                           
Month 5:  7                                                                                                                                           
Month 6:  3                                                                                                                                           
Month 7: 20                                                                                                                                           
Month 8: 29                                                                                                                                           
Month 9: 34(YearHighest)(ATH)                                                                                                                         
Month 10:  2                                                                                                                                          
Month 11: 10                                                                                                                                          
Month 12:  1                                                                                                                                          

Year2011:                                                                                                                                             
Month 1:  2                                                                                                                                           
Month 2:  7                                                                                                                                           
Month 3:  4                                                                                                                                           
Month 4:  5                                                                                                                                           
Month 5:  9                                                                                                                                           
Month 6:  3                                                                                                                                           
Month 7: 20                                                                                                                                           
Month 8:  9                                                                                                                                           
Month 9: 34(YearHighest)(ATH)                                                                                                                         
Month 10:  2                                                                                                                                          
Month 11: 10                                                                                                                                          
Month 12: 10
```

Here needs to use `max` function. It can max value from numbers of a list fast.

Answer (score 4):

Python has built-in function [max](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max), it's considered a good practice to use it.

Max in year:

```
max(temp_dict["2010"])
```

Max all time:

```
max(sum(temp_dict.values(), []))
```

---

`sum(lists, [])` does list flattening, equivalent to

```
[] + lists[0] + lists[1]...
```

Comment: Whoa, you threw a secret `sum-list-flatten` move in there. Might confuse folks. Might just consider `max(month_value for year in temp_dict.values() for month_value in year)`. Although hey, nested generators confuse folks all the time, too.

Comment: You're right, it is not obvious. I've put in a little explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a builtin function `max` you can utilize:

```
for key in temp_dict:
    print("Year", key,":")
    temps = temp_dict[key]
    max_temp = max(temps)
    max_index = temps.index(max_temp)
    for index, temps in enumerate(temps):
        r = "Month "+str(index+1)+":%3d"%temps
        if index == max_index:
            r += "(YearHighest)(ATH)"
        print(r)
```

Comment: What about two (or more) months with same max temperature?

Comment: @soon That's trivial. You could delete the max that's already found, and use `max` again, to see if there are two same max.

Comment: Removing previous max temperature is overhead, you could just compare `temps` with `max_temp` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
temp_dict= {
    "2010": [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 20, 29, 34, 2, 10, 1],
    "2011": [2, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 20, 9, 34, 2, 10, 10]
}

# defines the max of all years with a list comprehension
global_max_temp = max([ max(year_temps) for year_temps in temp_dict.values() ])

# iterates through each year
for year, temps in temp_dict.items():
    print("Year {}".format(year))
    for i, temp in enumerate(temps):
        # prepares the output
        temp_string = ["Month{}: {}".format(i+1, temp)]

        # builds a list of flags to be displayed
        flags = []
        if temp == max(temps):
            # max in year flag
            flags.append("YearHighest")
        if temp == global_max_temp:
            # absolute max flag
            flags.append("ATH")

        # joins temp_string and flags in a single line and prints it
        print(" ".join(temp_string + [ "({})".format(flag) for flag in flags ]))
```

Useful links from Python's documentation: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate), [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), [max](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max)